# Can lim sup En = Ω happens and, at the same time, P(En) → 0?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I was thinking if we use the outer measure of Borel in [0,1] and the Vitali set we may have the result. But I am not sure about lim sup of Vitali set in this case is [0,1]. Is it?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Write $n=2^k+i$, where $i \in [0, 2^k-1]$, and let $E_n:= \left[\frac{i}{2^k}, \frac{i+1}{2^k} \right]$.  Let $P$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.  Then $\lim \sup E_n = [0,1]$, but $P(E_n) \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot!